# Easy way to have a VB.Net WindowsForms application work as a web app?

Tags: vb.net

I have made a small text based game using VB.NET in a Windows Forms application but it seems that people are a bit hesitent when it comes to downloading exe files. What would an easy way to have it work as a web application without having to rewrite the entire code?

Comment: separate all the logic into different libraries so that they can be reused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't an "easy" way to turn it into a web application. You can take all of your logic and put it into libraries (Class Library), but you'll need to write new front-end code for both the desktop and web.

If you are wanting the web to accept user input and such without constant reloading, you'll also need to make a web service to talk to using jQuery or the like.

For what it's worth, if anyone is hesitant to download an EXE, then they don't need it. I used to publish installations for VB6 applications on my website years ago, and I had downloads and referrals from all over the place, including educational institutions.

Also, if you are direct linking to an EXE, consider packaging it up in a ZIP along with a readme file.

Comment: Thanks for the advice :)

Comment: @weeurey You're welcome. I wish there was a simple answer, but it really is quite complex. Your only option if you want to skip using web services and such is to make a Javascript version that runs within the browser, which obviously requires full rewrite.

Comment: @weeurey If you found this useful and/or an acceptable response, I'd appreciate an Upvote and/or Mark as Answer. :-)